# Cannot clone test case - filter plan opens in next page

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I cannot clone test case, because of filtering test plans not working as expected. Is that a bug, or I am doing something wrong?

I have installed Kiwi with Docker on Debian 9. Kiwi version 6.3. Using Firefox 60.4.0esr.

When trying to clone test case I have to select test plan. Kiwi asks me to filter test plans, but button "filter" redirects to results in next page (instead i.e. opening in new window or below button). I can tick a plan there, but there is no way to submit it. Test plan names only redirects me to test plan page. When going back and try to clone case anyway, it throws me "this field is required" under "filter" button.

How to fix that?

Comment: Well I can't reproduce this on the demo website so we need more information to figure it out. Can you post screenshots or even better short video of how you open the test case and try to clone it and where it doesn't work?  If possible try to reproduce against the demo instance.

Comment: Sure, here you are: https://imgur.com/a/hbiMofd

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Reported in 
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/695

Comment: I was looking for this in issues, this one was opened yesterday. I wasn't sure if this is a bug or error in my configuration, so I asked here.